# Comparing how relationship between two variables changes after event

Tags: regression, t-test

I would like to compare how an event changes the relationship between two variables. Let's say for instance I have two variables $x$ and $y$, firstly I run a regression to check their relationship such that prior to the event I have the regression

$y_{pre}  \sim   x_{pre}$

and post event I have:

$y_{post}  \sim   x_{post}$

Is there a way to check whether the relationship between $x$ and $y$ changes after the event? I was thinking of using some sort of two sample t-test but I don't think that's appropriate, so if anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a binary dummy variable that is 0 before and 1 after. Run the regression with the dummy variable and an interaction between x and the dummy variable. The interaction coefficient will tell you the difference in coefficients before and after the event. Check it for significance and you're good to go!

Comment: Ah ok, so basically the new regression should look like: $x + Dummy + x*Dummy$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThePlowKing It's `y~Event*x`, where Event in the dummy.

Comment: @user2974951 Awesome, thanks!